# Draw circle on a new layer in Photoshop using cep/Javascript

Tags: javascript, adobe, draw, layer, photoshop-script

for a photoshop plugin project, I would like to create a new layer, give it a name, draw a circle of a specific color. I'm coding in Javascript and using the framework CEP.

The coordinates of the circle to be drawn look like this:

linesStr: "2287,3474 | 2268,3430 | 2255,3398 | 2255,3360 | 2255,3315 | 2255,3264 | 2255,3207 | 2261,3162 | 2331,3047 | 2389,3003 | 2433.2977 | 2484.2965 | 2541.2946 | 2580.2946 | 2618.2946 | 2650.2952 | 2688.2971 | 2720.2990 | 2745.3022 | 2764.3054 | 2777.3086 | 2790 , 3124 | 2803.3162 | 2803.3207 | 2803.3251 | 2803.3296 | 2783.3360 | 2752.3411 | 2726.3449 | 2707.3493 | 2688.3519 | 2637.3557 | 2611.3570 | 2592.3576 | 2573.3576 | 2554.3589 | 2548.3589 | 2541.3589 | 2535.3589 | 2529.3589 | 2516.3589 | 2510.3589 | 2503.3583 | 2497.3576 | 2497.3557 | 2497.3551 | 2497 , 3525 | 2497.3512 | 2497.3493 | 2490.3481 | 2490.3455 | 2478.3442 | 2478.3423 | 2478.3417 | 2471.3398 | 2465.3391 | 2459.3372 | 2452.3366 | 2446.3366 * 2401.3328 | 2389.3321 | 2382.3321 | 2376.3321 | 2369.3315 | 2350.3309 | 2344.3302 ".

These coordinates represent this note:
[image]

So the result should look like this :

[image]

I will be happy to accept any help !

Comment: So what are you struggling with exactly? Create a shape or use lasso to create a selection from your coordinates

Comment: Draw on a new layer the shape with the coordinates I have in my string. :) I don't know if I need the lasso, I never did this before. The only links I saw about this what that : https://gist.github.com/vladocar/1307987

Comment: I did it by deleting the paths stored in photoshop :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little bit of adjusting the script you supplied can be adjusted to take your coordinates. You just need to supply the shape an array which'll create a path.

The coordinates you supplied have an extraneous asterisk in it instead of a pipe delimited. As well as dots instead of commas. They are also upside down. Photoshop starts at the top left, and y increases down the image. I've compensated for that.

Also matching pixels to vector coordinates is resolution dependant. At the moment the image is 72 dpi. if that changes it'll offset the path size.

I replaced the fill with a draw line .

[image: green shape from script]

```
function DrawShape(arr) 
{
    
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var y = arr.length;
    var i = 0;

    // get original height
    var imageHeight = app.activeDocument.height.value;
    
    var lineArray = [];
    for (i = 0; i < y; i++) 
    {
        lineArray[i] = new PathPointInfo;
        lineArray[i].kind = PointKind.CORNERPOINT;

        // invert Y
        arr[i][1] = imageHeight - arr[i][1];

        lineArray[i].anchor = arr[i];
        lineArray[i].leftDirection = lineArray[i].anchor;
        lineArray[i].rightDirection = lineArray[i].anchor;
    }

    var lineSubPathArray = new SubPathInfo();
    lineSubPathArray.closed = true;
    lineSubPathArray.operation = ShapeOperation.SHAPEADD;
    lineSubPathArray.entireSubPath = lineArray;
    var myPathItem = doc.pathItems.add("myPath", [lineSubPathArray]);
    

    // =======================================================
    var idsetd = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
    var desc100 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
    var ref24 = new ActionReference();
    var idChnl = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
    var idfsel = charIDToTypeID( "fsel" );
    ref24.putProperty( idChnl, idfsel );
    desc100.putReference( idnull, ref24 );
    var idT = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
    var ref25 = new ActionReference();
    var idPath = charIDToTypeID( "Path" );
    var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
    var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
    ref25.putEnumerated( idPath, idOrdn, idTrgt );
    desc100.putReference( idT, ref25 );
    var idVrsn = charIDToTypeID( "Vrsn" );
    desc100.putInteger( idVrsn, 1 );
    var idvectorMaskParams = stringIDToTypeID( "vectorMaskParams" );
    desc100.putBoolean( idvectorMaskParams, true );
    executeAction( idsetd, desc100, DialogModes.NO );


    // draw a pixel line in red around the path
    stroke_line(2, 215, 5, 5);

    // remove selectrion path to pixels
    deselect_path();

    // select nothing
    app.activeDocument.selection.deselect();

    // var desc88 = new ActionDescriptor();
    // var ref60 = new ActionReference();
    // ref60.putClass(stringIDToTypeID("contentLayer"));
    // desc88.putReference(charIDToTypeID("null"), ref60);
    // var desc89 = new ActionDescriptor();
    // var desc90 = new ActionDescriptor();
    // var desc91 = new ActionDescriptor();
    // desc91.putDouble(charIDToTypeID("Rd  "), 0.000000); // R
    // desc91.putDouble(charIDToTypeID("Grn "), 0.000000); // G
    // desc91.putDouble(charIDToTypeID("Bl  "), 0.000000); // B
    // var id481 = charIDToTypeID("RGBC");
    // desc90.putObject(charIDToTypeID("Clr "), id481, desc91);
    // desc89.putObject(charIDToTypeID("Type"), stringIDToTypeID("solidColorLayer"), desc90);
    // desc88.putObject(charIDToTypeID("Usng"), stringIDToTypeID("contentLayer"), desc89);
    // executeAction(charIDToTypeID("Mk  "), desc88, DialogModes.NO);
    
    // myPathItem.remove();
}


function stroke_line(strokewidth, R, G, B)
{
// =======================================================
var idStrk = charIDToTypeID( "Strk" );
var desc2613 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idWdth = charIDToTypeID( "Wdth" );
desc2613.putInteger( idWdth, strokewidth );
var idLctn = charIDToTypeID( "Lctn" );
var idStrL = charIDToTypeID( "StrL" );
var idInsd = charIDToTypeID( "Insd" );
desc2613.putEnumerated( idLctn, idStrL, idInsd );
var idOpct = charIDToTypeID( "Opct" );
var idPrc = charIDToTypeID( "#Prc" );
desc2613.putUnitDouble( idOpct, idPrc, 100.000000 ); // opacity
var idMd = charIDToTypeID( "Md  " );
var idBlnM = charIDToTypeID( "BlnM" );
var idNrml = charIDToTypeID( "Nrml" );
desc2613.putEnumerated( idMd, idBlnM, idNrml );
var idClr = charIDToTypeID( "Clr " );
var desc2614 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idRd = charIDToTypeID( "Rd  " );
desc2614.putDouble( idRd, R ); // RED
var idGrn = charIDToTypeID( "Grn " );
desc2614.putDouble( idGrn, G ); // GREEN
var idBl = charIDToTypeID( "Bl  " );
desc2614.putDouble( idBl, B ); // BLUE
var idRGBC = charIDToTypeID( "RGBC" );
desc2613.putObject( idClr, idRGBC, desc2614 );
executeAction( idStrk, desc2613, DialogModes.NO );
}

function deselect_path()
{
    //deselect path
    // =======================================================
    var id630 = charIDToTypeID( "Dslc" );
    var desc154 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var id631 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
    var ref127 = new ActionReference();
    var id632 = charIDToTypeID( "Path" );
    ref127.putClass( id632 );
    desc154.putReference( id631, ref127 );
    executeAction( id630, desc154, DialogModes.NO );
}


var myArr = [
[2287,3474],
[2268,3430],
[2255,3398],
[2255,3360],
[2255,3315],
[2255,3264],
[2255,3207],
[2261,3162],
[2331,3047],
[2389,3003],
[2433,2977],
[2484,2965],
[2541,2946],
[2580,2946],
[2618,2946],
[2650,2952],
[2688,2971],
[2720,2990],
[2745,3022],
[2764,3054],
[2777,3086],
[2790,3124],
[2803,3162],
[2803,3207],
[2803,3251],
[2803,3296],
[2783,3360],
[2752,3411],
[2726,3449],
[2707,3493],
[2688,3519],
[2637,3557],
[2611,3570],
[2592,3576],
[2573,3576],
[2554,3589],
[2548,3589],
[2541,3589],
[2535,3589],
[2529,3589],
[2516,3589],
[2510,3589],
[2503,3583],
[2497,3576],
[2497,3557],
[2497,3551],
[2497,3525],
[2497,3512],
[2497,3493],
[2490,3481],
[2490,3455],
[2478,3442],
[2478,3423],
[2478,3417],
[2471,3398],
[2465,3391],
[2459,3372],
[2452,3366],
[2446,3366],
[2401,3328],
[2389,3321],
[2382,3321],
[2376,3321],
[2369,3315],
[2350,3309],
[2344,3302],
]
DrawShape(myArr);
```

Comment: Hello @GhoulFool, when I try to use the function multiple times, I have an alert asking me for save the path. Do you know how to avoid this please ?

Comment: @LaurentQ. That's probably because Photoshop needs unique path layer names. You can rename it or delete path after you've used it with `myPathItem.remove();` Either that or it's a dialogue thing. If that doesn't work put this at the beginning of your script `displayDialogs = DialogModes.ERROR; // Errors only`

Comment: Hello @GhoulFool, is it the same solution for a InDesign plugin ?

Comment: @Fitspade I've not tried. In my limited knowledge of ID: they both used JavaScript, although ID is more geared up for dot notation.

Comment: Ok, thank you @GhoulFool I'll try !

Comment: Hi @GhoulFool, for drawing number 3, is it possible not to have this binding that joins the 2 ends of the line ? Because I can not remove this joint.

Comment: It's been a while, but I think that's handled by `lineSubPathArray.closed = true;`